# Extraer datos de una página web usando curl php

Tags: php, curl

Les pido alguna ayuda para resolver el error de este código :

```
<?php 
$id=$_GET['id'];
function videos($url)
{
    $ch = curl_init();
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
    $head[] = "Connection: keep-alive";
    $head[] = "Keep-Alive: 300";
    $head[] = "Accept-Charset: ISO-8859-1,utf-8;q=0.7,*;q=0.7";
    $head[] = "Accept-Language: en-us,en;q=0.5";
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_USERAGENT, 'Mozilla/5.0 (Linux; Android 4.4.2; Nexus 4 Build/KOT49H) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/34.0.1847.114 Mobile Safari/537.36');
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, $head);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST, FALSE);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, FALSE);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_TIMEOUT, 60);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_CONNECTTIMEOUT, 60);
    @curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, TRUE);
    $page = curl_exec($ch);
    curl_close($ch);
    return $page;
}

$url = videos('http://www.m.com/videos/?v='.$id);


if (preg_match('#\[{file:[^"]*"([^"]*)"#',$url, $page)) {
    $sd = $page[1];
} else {
    $sd = 'error';
}
echo $sd;
?>
```

se supone que extrae la url del vídeo pero solo error.

Comment: _se supone que extrae la url del vídeo pero solo error._ ¿Puedes editar la pregunta colocando el mensaje de error que recibes?, de esa forma será más fácil ayudarte.

Comment: no encuentra el enlace si utilizo **file_get_contents** funciona bien pero no es muy seguro y prefiero a serlo con **curl**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

luego de una búsqueda encontré la solución:

```
<?php 
$url = 'http://www.m.com/videos/?v=7826421';
$ch = curl_init();
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url );
curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_HEADER,0);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, true );
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_ENCODING, "gzip,deflate");    
$response = curl_exec($ch); //La variable response almacena el response de la pagina.

curl_close($ch);  

if (preg_match('#\[{file:[^"]*"([^"]*)"#',$response, $page)) {
    $sd = $page[1];
} else {
    $sd = 'error';
}
echo $sd;
?>
```

Se las comparto por si a alguien le sirve. Saludes